# Not able to copy file from one location to the other

Tags: python

**Code**

```
import os
import shutil
from os import listdir
source = os.listdir('C:\Users\surau\Documents\GUI_Screen')
destination = os.listdir('C:\Users\surau\Documents')
for files in source:
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(source, destination)  
    break
```

**Error:**

```
shutil.copy2(source, destination)  
File "D:\Python2.5\lib\shutil.py", line 89, in copy2
if os.path.isdir(dst):
File "D:\Python2.5\lib\ntpath.py", line 270, in isdir
st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

not able to get the file fron source to destination can u help me regarding this query.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the `destination` at `shutil.copy2(source, destination)`
You cannot pass `listdir` because it's a `list`.

Docs for `listdir` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

Just change to `destination = "C:\\Users\surau\\Documents\\"`

And `shutil.copy2(source, destination)` to `shutil.copy2(files, destination)`

Also pay attention your `break` indention is currently after the first for iteration.

Comment: import os
import shutil
from os import listdir
source = os.listdir('C:\Users\surau\Documents\GUI_Screen')
destination = 'C:\Users\surau\Documents '
for files in source:
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(files, destination)  
        break

Comment: @Sachin kumar paste your new code at the question edit not at the comment, indention cannot be copied! also if you have error (traceback paste it two)

Comment: @Sachin kumar paste you new code at the YOUR QUESTION don't try to edit my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

- You are iterating over a list of files but you pass the list it self as argument to the copy function. the copy function however expects 'strings' or 'buffer' as argument **not** a list, as indicated by the error message.
- Your are using the content of the destination folder as destination
- You break your loop after the first file

i guess what you are trying is:

```
import os
import shutil
from os import listdir
source = os.listdir('C:\Users\surau\Documents\GUI_Screen')
destination = 'C:\Users\surau\Documents'
for files in source:
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.copy2(files, destination)  
        break
```